# how to check global variable is defined or not in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one global variable in one JavaScript file and I using it in another JavaScript file.

but sometime we not use that JavaScript file(where we define Global variable) so I am getting error like var_Name is not defined error. So any way in JavaScript to check variable is defined or not and if its not defined than how to defined that variable run time.

```
var_Global?var_Abc=var_Global:var_Global=somevalue
```

when if global variable is defined than I want to assign that variable to another variable and if not than I want to define that variable.

Thanks.

Comment: literally do that? "if ([typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) varname === "undefined") { console.log("varname is not defined"); }"

Comment: down voter please let me know what I have done wrong in this question so I can improve in next time.Thanks

Comment: @PravinTukadiya I'm not the one who down-voted the question, but my guess would be that it is because there most probably is a blog post or SO question about this AKA that this question is on google for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file1.js

```
var x = 'foo';
```

file2.js

```
if (typeof x !== 'undefined') { 
    console.log('x is defined') 
} else { 
    console.log('x is undefined')
    //define x
    x = 'foo'
}
```

Comment: ok let me check this.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

file1.js

```
var x = 30;
```

file2.js

```
var x = x || 10;
```

This is a common technique to check for a variable value in such contexts, specially for non-strict mode.
So `x || 10` will first see if x has any value? In case x is `undefined` due to non-inclusion of the the file, then it would get a value 10. If x was defined, it would take value from file1.js. You can change this value 10 to any value you want.

Comment: Your code in `file2.js` will result in a `ReferenceError` in strict mode. Better to use `typeof`.

Comment: getting error x is not defined.

Comment: @PravinTukadiya Are you using strict mode?

Comment: no I am using in the ext js

Comment: Why downvote? OP hasn't specified that he is using strict mode!

Comment: Not sure why you think there is a downvote. Anyway, the OP does not need to mention that he is using strict mode. You should post code which runs in strict mode. For instance, if the code is being transpiled by Babel or TypeScript, it is likely that it is being transpiled into strict mode. Your code also has the problem that it will replace any non-truthy value of `x` (`false`, `0`, `""`, `null`) with 10.

Comment: @PravinTukadiya
To be fair, code in file2.js will fail in non-strict mode as well, you would need to add var there, like this:
`var x = x || 10;`

Comment: @torazaburo There was one earlier! Also, point taken but in this case he is using extjs and extjs framework itself doesn't play nicely with strict mode unless you make arrangements. So the solution was with context and not generic.

Comment: @ArtūrsLataks Sorry, my bad. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below ways :**

**1.** check for undefined

```
if (window.var_Global === undefined) {
    window.var_Global = 'hi';
}
```

**2.** check for property

```
if (!window.hasOwnProperty('var_Global')) {
    window.var_Global = 'hi';
}
```

**3.** using logical OR (||) operator

```
window.var_Global = window.var_Global || 'hi';
```

**4.** To check all the Global variables.

```
Object.keys( window ); // return array of all the global variables.
```